# SSH Port Forwarding Using a Jump Host

Tags: ssh-tunneling, aws

I am trying to figure out how to get a jump host to work with AWS Cloud9. Below is a diagram taken from the [blog post](http://france.micronauticsresearch.com/blog/2020/09/28/using-aws-cloud9-with-jump-server.html) (on my staging server) there I am writing on the subject. Please refer to the blog post (just under 3000 words) for the entire scenario.

[image: diagram]

Here is the 4-party initialization sequence performed by an administrator using the client (laptop):

1. The administrator logs into the target server (`$C9_TARGET_HOST`) using a (command line) terminal, and leaves the terminal open.
2. The administrator logs into the jump host (`$C9_JUMP_HOST`) using a second (command line) terminal, and leaves the terminal open.
3. An administrator opens a port (`$C9_JUMP_PORT`) on the jump host
       to accept `ssh` connections from AWS Cloud9.
4. The administrator points a web browser at the
       Cloud9 web console
       to begin defining a Cloud9 environment.
5. Once the administrator reaches the web page
       where the Cloud9 ssh key is available, they copy it to the clipboard.
6. The administrator uses the open terminal connected to the target server to:

     Add the Cloud9 ssh key to
     `~/.ssh/authorized_hosts`
     .
  Add a new
  `host`
  block to
  `~/.ssh/config`
  that makes it easier to define a reverse ssh port forwarding tunnel from
          the target server to the jump host.

The administrator uses the open terminal connected to the jump host to:

  Add the Cloud9 ssh key to
  `~/.ssh/authorized_hosts`
  .

Add a new `host` block to `~/.ssh/config` that makes it easier to forward `ssh` commands
        from Cloud9 to the target server.

The administrator defines a reverse `ssh` port forwarding tunnel from the target server to the jump host,
    which means that the jump host will connect back to the target server via the tunnel and forward `ssh`
    commands when a connection is made to the specified port (`$C9_JUMP_PORT`) on the jump host.

```
ssh -fNR \
$C9_JUMP_HOST:$C9_JUMP_PORT:localhost:22 $C9_JUMP_USER@$C9_JUMP_HOST
```

I wonder if the `-T` option might be helpful?
    Should `nohup` be used?

The administrator creates a reverse port forwarded tunnel using the definition they just created.
    `nohup` is used when creating the tunnel so it remains in place once the administrator logs off.

After defining the jump host in the Cloud9 web console, the administrator presses the
    Next step button.

Cloud9 attempts to reach the jump host.

Cloud9 attempts to reach the target server via the jump host.

If successful, Cloud9 advances the administrator's web page to the next step.

The administrator clicks on each Next step button that appears until the Cloud9 environment is defined.

I would be happy to provide credit in the blog posting to whomever might provide the solution.

Comment: Many of [these questions/answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssh-tunneling) look like they would help. Just seeing if there are one or two specific ones...

Comment: Thanks @roaima. I have never seen any articles or discussions about initiating a 4-party handshake from a target system to a jump host. If you know of any, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks @fra-san. The suggested answer from Georg Mach appears to be very promising.

Comment: The diagram shows the client and target in the same NAT zone, in which case the jump host is unnecessary. Now, that's not what you describe but it is what you show

Comment: Sorry but like others, I can not workout what you are trying to do. Edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: @fra-san Good questions! I will update the article today (and add an explanation of the 4 party handshake sequence), try out some code, and then update my question with answers to your questions.

Comment: @roaima Hopefully the edits I make today will clarify.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Will do, thanks.

Comment: Am I missing something? You say "Hopefully the edits I make today will clarify." However the last edit was mine. Where is this edit?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Today is not over yet. I am just about to make some changes. Please remain calm.

Comment: Perhaps I should discontinue using StackExchange.

Comment: Yes, @fra-san, Target can reach Jump host because it has a public IP and is not behind NAT. I have not tested this latest scenario, only written it up. I'll probably test it tomorrow. So many scenarios...

Comment: (Sorry, re-posting -- to remove some irrelevant advice given in my previous comments) Now your question is self-contained, which is really good. But it is not clear what you are ultimately asking. Is something not working as expected? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to to is to establish a reverse tunnel from the Target (private server) to the Jump Host (public server) so that you could establish a connection from AWS to Target, correct?

In that case, the reverse tunnel has to be built from the Target, so there you could invoke something like

```
ssh -f -N -R $JUMPER:$PORT:localhost:22 $USER@$JUMPER
```

Maybe you also want to try out "autossh" instead of "ssh", to keep your reverse tunnel open. The command uses an additional parameter for a monitor port:

```
autossh -M $MONITORPORT -f -N -R $JUMPER:$PORT:localhost:22 $USER@$JUMPER
```

If you use only the part $PORT:localhost:22, you have to go to the target in two steps:

1. From AWS ssh to the Jump Server
2. From the Jump Server ssh to localhost:$PORT to use the reverse tunnel.

Hope that helps,
Georg

Comment: I will check it out and get back to you. Never knew about autossh. Never thought about building the tunnel from target. Many thanks!

Comment: is there anyway to use the -J option with autossh?, trying to do the same here but want to jump before doing anything